# Same file path found in only one test function, not found in other. How is it possible?

Tags: java, junit

I'm running these junit tests in eclipse:

```
class KGramIndexTestTest {

    @Test
    void testGetTerms() {
        KGramIndex kgIndex = new KGramIndex(2);

        File f = new File("../test/text.txt");
        try {
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
            Tokenizer tok = new Tokenizer( reader, true, false, true, "../patterns.txt" );
            while ( tok.hasMoreTokens() ) {
                String token = tok.nextToken();
                kgIndex.insert(token);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String wildcard = "hel*o";
        List<String> terms = kgIndex.getTerms(wildcard);
        assertEquals(terms.size(), 1);
        assertEquals(terms.get(0), "hello");
    }
    @Test
    void testGetKGrams() {
        KGramIndex kgIndex = new KGramIndex(2);

        File f = new File("../test/text.txt");
        try {
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
            Tokenizer tok = new Tokenizer( reader, true, false, true, "../patterns.txt" );
            while ( tok.hasMoreTokens() ) {
                String token = tok.nextToken();
                kgIndex.insert(token);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String wildcard = "hel*o";
        List<String> kGrams = kgIndex.getKGrams(wildcard);
        System.out.println("The k-grams");
        System.out.println(kGrams);
        assertEquals(4, kGrams.size());

        List<String> bigrams = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        bigrams.add("^h");
        bigrams.add("he");
        bigrams.add("el");
        bigrams.add("o$");
        assertTrue(kGrams.containsAll(bigrams));
    }


}
```

the second test function succeeds, but the first fails and produces a `FileNotFoundException`:

[image]

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../test/text.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:196)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:139)
    at ir.KGramIndexTestTest.testGetTerms(KGramIndexTestTest.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
```

This baffles me, because the same file path is being used in both functions. How can it not be found in one of the functions, and work fine in the other?

EDIT: I tried to close the `reader`, but it didn't help.

EDIT 2: I tried a third variant, but I still get `FileNotFoundException`. The line in question is this line in `testGetTerms`:

```
reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
```

The third variant:

```
class KGramIndexTestTest {

    @Test
    void testGetTerms() {
        KGramIndex kgIndex = new KGramIndex(2);

        File f = new File("../test/text.txt");
        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
            Tokenizer tok = new Tokenizer( reader, true, false, true, "../patterns.txt" );
            while ( tok.hasMoreTokens() ) {
                String token = tok.nextToken();
                kgIndex.insert(token);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String wildcard = "hel*o";
        List<String> terms = kgIndex.getTerms(wildcard);
        assertEquals(terms.size(), 1);
        assertEquals(terms.get(0), "hello");
    }
    @Test
    void testGetKGrams() {
        KGramIndex kgIndex = new KGramIndex(2);

        File f = new File("../test/text.txt");
        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
            Tokenizer tok = new Tokenizer( reader, true, false, true, "../patterns.txt" );
            while ( tok.hasMoreTokens() ) {
                String token = tok.nextToken();
                kgIndex.insert(token);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if(reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String wildcard = "hel*o";
        List<String> kGrams = kgIndex.getKGrams(wildcard);
        System.out.println("The k-grams");
        System.out.println(kGrams);
        assertEquals(4, kGrams.size());

        List<String> bigrams = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        bigrams.add("^h");
        bigrams.add("he");
        bigrams.add("el");
        bigrams.add("o$");
        assertTrue(kGrams.containsAll(bigrams));
    }    
}
```

EDIT 3:
I tried to use `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll`, but I get the EXACT same result.

EDIT 4:
I also tried to put all the asserts in the working test case `testKGrams`. What happened is that the previously working `InputStreamReader` initialization stopped working and threw `FileNotFoundException`:

UPDATE 2:

KGramIndex.java:

```
public class KGramIndex {

    HashMap<Integer,String> id2term = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    HashMap<String,Integer> term2id = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    HashMap<String,List<KGramPostingsEntry>> index = new HashMap<String,List<KGramPostingsEntry>>();

    int lastTermID = -1;

    int K = 3;

    public KGramIndex(int k) {
        K = k;
        if (k <= 0) {
            System.err.println("The K-gram index can't be constructed for a negative K value");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private int generateTermID() {
        return ++lastTermID;
    }

    public int getK() {
        return K;
    }

    public int size() {
            return index.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTokenKGrams(String token){
            ArrayList<String> kGrams = new ArrayList<String>();
            int start = 0;
        int end = start+K;
        int noOfKGrams = token.length() - end + 1; 
        String kGram;
        int startCurr, endCurr;
        for (int i=0; i<noOfKGrams; i++) {
            startCurr = start + i;
            endCurr = end + i;
            kGram = token.substring(startCurr, endCurr);
            kGrams.add(kGram);  
        }
        return kGrams;
    }

    public List<String> getKGrams(String token) {

            int index = token.indexOf("*");
            if(index != -1) {
                String left = "^"+token.substring(0, index);
                String right = token.substring(index+1, token.length())+"$";
                List<String> leftKGrams = getTokenKGrams(left);
                List<String> rightKGrams = getTokenKGrams(right);
                leftKGrams.addAll(rightKGrams);
                return leftKGrams;
            }
            return getTokenKGrams(token);
    }

    public List<String> getTerms(String wildcard){
            int index = wildcard.indexOf("*");
            if(index == -1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("wildcard must contain a '*'.");
            }

            List<String> kGrams = getKGrams(wildcard);
            List<String> kGramContainers = new ArrayList<String>();

            List<KGramPostingsEntry> intersection = getPostings(kGrams.get(0));
            List<KGramPostingsEntry> newPostings;
            for(int i = 1; i<kGrams.size(); i++) {
                newPostings = getPostings(kGrams.get(i));
                intersection = intersect(intersection, newPostings);
            }
            String term;
            for(KGramPostingsEntry entry : intersection) {
                term = id2term.get(entry.tokenID);
                kGramContainers.add(term);
            }

        StringBuilder regexBuilder = new StringBuilder(wildcard);
        regexBuilder.insert(index, ".");
        String regex = regexBuilder.toString();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i=0; i<kGramContainers.size(); i++) {
                term = kGramContainers.get(i);
                boolean matches = Pattern.matches(regex, term);
                if(matches) {
                    result.add(term);
                }
            }
            return result;
    }

    private List<KGramPostingsEntry> intersect(List<KGramPostingsEntry> pA, List<KGramPostingsEntry> pB) {
        ListIterator<KGramPostingsEntry> iterA = pA.listIterator();
        ListIterator<KGramPostingsEntry> iterB = pB.listIterator();

        List<KGramPostingsEntry> result = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
        KGramPostingsEntry entryA = iterA.next();
        KGramPostingsEntry entryB = iterB.next();

        while(true) {

                if(entryA.tokenID == entryB.tokenID) {
                    result.add(entryA);
                    if(iterA.hasNext() && iterB.hasNext()) {
                        entryA = iterA.next();
                        entryB = iterB.next();
                    }else {
                        break;
                    }
                }else if(entryA.tokenID > entryB.tokenID) { 
                    if(iterB.hasNext()) 
                        entryB = iterB.next();
                    else 
                        break;
                }
                else {
                    if(iterA.hasNext()) 
                        entryA = iterA.next();
                    else 
                        break;
                }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public void insert( String token ) {

            if (term2id.get(token) != null) {
                return;
            }

        id2term.put(++lastTermID, token);
        term2id.put(token, lastTermID);

            // is word long enough? for example, "a" can be bigrammed and trigrammed but not four-grammed.
            // K must be <= token.length + 2. "ab". K must be <= 4
            List<KGramPostingsEntry> postings = null;
            if(K > token.length() + 2) {
                return;
            }else if(K == token.length() + 2) {
                // insert the one K-gram "^<String token>$" into index
                postings = index.get("^"+token+"$");
                if (postings == null) {
                    KGramPostingsEntry newEntry = new KGramPostingsEntry(lastTermID);
                    ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry> newList = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
                    newList.add(newEntry);
                    index.put("^"+token+"$", newList);
                }
                // No need to do anything if the posting already exists, so no else clause. There is only one possible term in this case
                // Return since we are done
                return;
            }else {
                // We get here if there is more than one k-gram in our term
                // insert all k-grams in token into index
                int start = 0;
                int end = start+K;
                //add ^ and $ to token.
                token = "^"+token+"$";
                int noOfKGrams = token.length() - end + 1; 
                // get K-Grams
                String kGram;
                int startCurr, endCurr;
                for (int i=0; i<noOfKGrams; i++) {

                    startCurr = start + i;
                    endCurr = end + i;


                    kGram = token.substring(startCurr, endCurr);

                    postings = index.get(kGram);
                KGramPostingsEntry newEntry = new KGramPostingsEntry(lastTermID);
                    // if this k-gram has been seen before
                    if (postings != null) {
                        // Add this token to the existing postingsList.
                        // We can be sure that the list doesn't contain the token
                        // already, else we would previously have terminated the 
                        // execution of this function.
                        int lastTermInPostings = postings.get(postings.size()-1).tokenID;
                        if (lastTermID == lastTermInPostings) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        postings.add(newEntry);
                        index.put(kGram, postings);
                    }
                    // if this k-gram has not been seen before 
                    else {
                        ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry> newList = new ArrayList<KGramPostingsEntry>();
                        newList.add(newEntry);
                        index.put(kGram, newList);
                    }
                }
            }

    }

    /** Get postings for the given k-gram */
    public List<KGramPostingsEntry> getPostings(String kgram) {
        return index.get(kgram);
    }

    /** Get id of a term */
    public Integer getIDByTerm(String term) {
        return term2id.get(term);
    }

    /** Get a term by the given id */
    public String getTermByID(Integer id) {
        return id2term.get(id);
    }

    private static HashMap<String,String> decodeArgs( String[] args ) {
        HashMap<String,String> decodedArgs = new HashMap<String,String>();
        int i=0, j=0;
        while ( i < args.length ) {
            if ( "-p".equals( args[i] )) {
                i++;
                if ( i < args.length ) {
                    decodedArgs.put("patterns_file", args[i++]);
                }
            }
            else if ( "-f".equals( args[i] )) {
                i++;
                if ( i < args.length ) {
                    decodedArgs.put("file", args[i++]);
                }
            }
            else if ( "-k".equals( args[i] )) {
                i++;
                if ( i < args.length ) {
                    decodedArgs.put("k", args[i++]);
                }
            }
            else if ( "-kg".equals( args[i] )) {
                i++;
                if ( i < args.length ) {
                    decodedArgs.put("kgram", args[i++]);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.err.println( "Unknown option: " + args[i] );
                break;
            }
        }
        return decodedArgs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        HashMap<String,String> args = decodeArgs(arguments);

        int k = Integer.parseInt(args.getOrDefault("k", "3"));
        KGramIndex kgIndex = new KGramIndex(k);

        File f = new File(args.get("file"));
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        Tokenizer tok = new Tokenizer( reader, true, false, true, args.get("patterns_file") );
        while ( tok.hasMoreTokens() ) {
            String token = tok.nextToken();
            kgIndex.insert(token);
        }
        System.out.printf("Done with indexing. %d k-grams in index\n", kgIndex.size());

        String[] kgrams = args.get("kgram").split(" ");
        List<KGramPostingsEntry> postings = null;
        for (String kgram : kgrams) {
            if (kgram.length() != k) {
                System.err.println("Cannot search k-gram index: " + kgram.length() + "-gram provided instead of " + k + "-gram");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            if (postings == null) {
                    System.out.println("getting postings...");
                postings = kgIndex.getPostings(kgram);
            } else {
                postings = kgIndex.intersect(postings, kgIndex.getPostings(kgram));
            }
        }
        if (postings == null) {
            System.err.println("Found 0 posting(s)");
        } else {
            int resNum = postings.size();
            System.err.println("Found " + resNum + " posting(s)");

            if (resNum > 10) {
                System.err.println("The first 10 of them are:");
                resNum = 10;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < resNum; i++) {
                System.err.println(kgIndex.getTermByID(postings.get(i).tokenID));
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Tokenizer.java:

```
package ir;

import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;
import java.lang.System;



/** 
 *  This class performs tokenization of UTF-8 encoded text files. 
 */
public class Tokenizer {

    /**
     *  This flag should be set to 'true' if all letters should be
     *  turned into lowercase.
     */
    public boolean case_folding = true; 

    /**
     *  This flag should be set to 'true' if all diacritics (accents etc.)
     *  should be removed.
     */
    public boolean remove_diacritics = true; 

    /**
     *  This flag should be set to 'true' if all punctuation (full stops etc.)
     *  should be removed.
     */
    public boolean remove_punctuation = true; 

    /** 
     *  The size of the buffer should be considerably larger than
     *  the anticipated length of the longest token.
     */
    public static final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 100001;

    /** The reader from where tokens are read. */
    Reader reader;

    /** 
     *  Characters are read @code{BUFFER_LENGTH} characters at a
     *  time into @code{buf}.
     */
    char[] buf = new char[BUFFER_LENGTH];

    /** The current position in the buffer. */
    int ptr = 0;

    /** Starting position of current token, or -1 if we're between tokens. */
    int token_start = -1;

    /** The next tokens to emit. */
    ArrayList<String> token_queue = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** @code{true} if we've started reading tokens. */
    boolean started_reading = false;

    /** The patterns matching non-standard words (e-mail addresses, etc.) */
    ArrayList<Pattern> patterns = null;

    /** Special characters (with diacritics) can be translated into these characters. */
    public static final char[] SPECIAL_CHAR_MAPPING = {
    'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'C', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '*', 'O', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'Y', 'T', 'S', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'd', 'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', '/', 'o', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'y', 't', 'y', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'A', 'a', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'E', 'e', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'L', 'l', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'n', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'O', 'o', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'U', 'u', 'W', 'w', 'Y', 'y', 'Y', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z', 'Z', 'z' }; 


    /* ------------------------------ */


    /**
     *  Constructor
     *  @param reader The reader from which to read the text to be tokenized. 
     *  @param case_folding Should be set to <code>true</code> if every character
     *         should be translated into its lowercase counterpart.
     *  @param remove_diacritics Should be set to <code>true</code> if diacritics 
     *         should be removed (e.g. é will be e).
     *  @param remove_punctuation Should be set to <code>true</code> if punctuation 
     *         should be removed (useful in some applications).
     *  @param pattern_file The name of the file containing regular expressions
     *         for non-standard words (like dates, mail addresses, etc.).
     */
    public Tokenizer( Reader reader, boolean case_folding, boolean remove_diacritics, boolean remove_punctuation, String pattern_file ) {
    this.reader = reader;
    this.case_folding = case_folding;
    this.remove_diacritics = remove_diacritics;
    this.remove_punctuation = remove_punctuation;
    if ( pattern_file != null ) {
        readPatterns( pattern_file );
    }
    }


    /** 
     *  Returns true if the character is a punctuation character.
     */
    public boolean punctuation( char c ) {
    if ( c >= 32 && c <= 47 )
        return true;
    if ( c >= 58 && c <= 64 )
        return true;
    if ( c >= 91 && c <= 96 )
        return true;
    if ( c >= 123 && c <= 126 ) 
        return true;
    return false;
    }


    /**
     *  Read the patterns that match non-standard words  
     */
    private void readPatterns( String filename ) {
    patterns = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( filename ));
        while (( line = in.readLine()) != null ) {
        line = line.trim();
        if ( !line.startsWith( "//" ) && line.length() > 0 ) {
            patterns.add( Pattern.compile( line ));
        }
        }
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) {
        System.err.println( "Warning: IOException reading the regular expressions from file" );
    }
    catch ( PatternSyntaxException e ) {
        System.err.println( "ERROR: Malformed regular expression: " + line );
    }
    }


    /** 
     *  Normalizes letters by converting to lower-case and possibly
     *  removing diacritics. This method is also used for checking
     *  whether a character can occur in a token or not.
     *
     *  @return code{true} if the (normalized counterpart of the) character
     *   can occur within a token, and @code{false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean normalize( char[] buf, int ptr ) {
    char c = buf[ptr];
    if ( Character.isLetter( c )) {
        if ( remove_diacritics ) {
        // Remove diacritics by mapping to the closest character 
        // without diacritics.
        if ( c >= '\u00c0' && c <= '\u017e' ) {
            buf[ptr] = SPECIAL_CHAR_MAPPING[(int)(c-'\u00c0')];
        }
        }
        if ( case_folding ) {
        buf[ptr] = Character.toLowerCase( buf[ptr] );
        }
        return true;
    }
    if ( c >= '!' && c <= '~' ) {
        return true;
    }
    // This is not a character that can occur in a token.
    return false;
    }



    /**
     *  @return the @code{true} if there are more tokens to be
     *  read, and @code{false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean hasMoreTokens() throws IOException {
    if ( !started_reading ) {
        readTokens();
        started_reading = true;
    }
    if ( token_queue.size() == 0 ) 
        return readTokens();
    else 
        return true;
    }


    /**
     *  @return a String containing the next token, or @code{null} if there
     *  are no more tokens.
     */
    public String nextToken() throws IOException { 
    if ( token_queue.size() == 0 ) {
        if ( readTokens() )
        return token_queue.remove( 0 );
        else
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return token_queue.remove( 0 );
    }
    }


    /**
     *  Reads the next token. 
     */ 
    private boolean readTokens() throws IOException {
    if ( !started_reading ) {
        refillBuffer( 0 );
        started_reading = true;
    }
    boolean token_added_to_queue = false;
    while ( buf[ptr] != 0 ) {
        if ( token_start < 0 ) {
        if ( normalize( buf, ptr )) {
            // A token starts here
            token_start = ptr;
        }
        ptr++;
        }
        else {
        if ( normalize( buf, ptr )) {
            // We're in the middle of a token
            ptr++;
        }
        else {
            // Check for non-standard words
            token_added_to_queue = addTokensToQueue();
            token_start = -1;
            ptr++;
        }
        }
        if ( ptr == BUFFER_LENGTH ) {
        // The buffer has been read, so refill it
        if ( token_start >= 0 ) {
            // We're in the middle of a token. Copy the parts
            // of the token we have read already into the 
            // beginning of the buffer.
            System.arraycopy( buf, token_start, buf, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH-token_start );
            refillBuffer( BUFFER_LENGTH-token_start );
            ptr = BUFFER_LENGTH-token_start;
            token_start = 0;
        }
        else {
            refillBuffer( 0 );
            ptr = 0;
        }
        }
        if ( token_added_to_queue ) {
        return true;
        }
    }
    // We have reached end of input. 
    return false; 
    }


    /**
     *  Adds token to the queue
     */
    private boolean addTokensToQueue() {
    if ( token_start < 0 ) {
        return false;
    }
    String s = new String( buf, token_start, ptr-token_start );
    if ( patterns != null ) {
        // Now let's see if the string s matches one of the patterns 
        // for non-standard words
        for ( Pattern p : patterns ) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher( s );
        if ( m.find() ) {
            // The string contains a non-standard word. First check the prefix 
            // before the matching substring, then add the non-standard word  
            // to the token queue, then check the remainder of the string.
            addStandardTokensToQueue( s.substring(0, m.start() ));
            token_queue.add( m.group() );
            token_start += m.end();
            addTokensToQueue();
            return true;
        }
        }
    }
    // This string contains only standard words
    return addStandardTokensToQueue( s );
    }


    /**
     *  Adds standard tokens (i.e. tokens not matching any regular
     *  expression) to the queue.
     */
    private boolean addStandardTokensToQueue( String s ) {
    // This string s does not match any specific pattern.
    // Then split it, considering all punctuation symbols
    // to be separators.
    boolean tokens_found = false;
    StringBuffer smallbuf = new StringBuffer();
    for ( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ) {
        if ( punctuation( s.charAt( i ))) {
        // The string before the punctuation sign is a token
        // unless it is empty
        String t = smallbuf.toString();
        if ( t.length()>0 ) {
            token_queue.add( t );
            smallbuf = new StringBuffer();
            tokens_found = true;
        }
        if ( !remove_punctuation ) {
            token_queue.add( "" + s.charAt( i ));
            tokens_found = true;
        }
        }
        else {
        smallbuf.append( s.charAt( i ));
        }
    }
    // The string after the last punctuation sign is a token
    // unless it is empty
    String t = smallbuf.toString();
    if ( t.length()>0 ) {
        token_queue.add( t );
        tokens_found = true;
    }   
    return tokens_found;
    }


    /**
     *  Refills the buffer and adds end_of_file "\0" at the appropriate place.
     */
    private void refillBuffer( int start ) throws IOException {
    int chars_read = reader.read( buf, start, BUFFER_LENGTH-start );
    if ( chars_read >= 0 && chars_read < BUFFER_LENGTH-start ) {
        buf[chars_read] = 0;
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

close fileinputstream in both  methods in the finally block

Comment: ok.. To avoid this error. try to add common line of code in method with  "@BeforeClass" it will avoid loading of same file twice. and close the same file in the method with "@AfterClass "

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem. I've shown what I've done in EDIT 3.

Comment: @sahand : any luck?

Comment: Nope, none at all.

Comment: can you share KGramIndex file if it is ok ?

Comment: No.. KGramIndex.Java Tokenizer.java files

Comment: Sure, Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

When first test case testGetTerms has opened the file to read. For some security reason file is unable to opened by second test case. That's why it is throwing fileNotFound exception. According to oracle documentation as below:

```
**FileInputStream**
public FileInputStream(String name)
                throws FileNotFoundException
Creates a FileInputStream by opening a connection to an actual file, the file named by the path name name in the file system.
```

A new FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection.
First, if there is a security manager, its checkRead method is called with the name argument as its argument.

```
If the named file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading then a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

Parameters:
name - the system-dependent file name.
Throws:
FileNotFoundException - if the file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading.
SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkRead method denies read access to the file.
See Also:
SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Actually, it's the SECOND test function that succeeds in opening the file and reading it. The FIRST test case, `testGetTerms`, fails

Comment: It's a race condition. At first which test case is able to open the file connection that will succeed and second will get failed.

Comment: For testing purpose, you can create duplicate of same file at same location and use two different names in both the test cases.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could do that. A bit annoying that there doesn't seem to be a better way of solving the problem.

Comment: I told you temp solution only for confirmation purpose that file is locked, that's why failed test case is unable to open the file.

Comment: I tried to create two files. Nothing changed. Same problem in same function! So it cannot be race condition.